# JasperReports page size scaling

Tags: jasper-reports

Does anyone know if there is a tool out there for scaling a *JasperReports* report up or down to fit different page sizes? The scenario is say I create & layout all my reports in the LETTER size. I want to be able to change to say size A4 on the fly and have all the elements adjust accordingly in width & X position.

Right now I'm writing my own code to do the scaling but I wanted to put this out there in case somebody knows of a tool or something in the *JasperReports* framework that I can use.

**UPDATE**

I created an open source project for JasperReport scaling: https://github.com/flex-rental-solutions/jasper-reports-scaler

It's still fairly primitive but we use it in our app successfully. I'd be delighted to see it grow from community support.

Comment: Would there be any interest in creating an open source tool to do this either as a standalone tool or something that could be included in the JasperReports framework? I have created a simple (working) scaler in our app and have thought about open sourcing it. It's really very simple like barely 100 lines of code. But if it could be open source the community could make it much better. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

open the report with xml or text editor and add these two lines:

`<Page width>` 210mm `</Page width>`

`<Page Hieght>` 297mm `</Page Hieght>`

after this line:

```
`<Page>`
```